# Open existing form with button

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a login form, from which i want to open a "Home form", which i obviously made myself, when login is success. You can look at the part where it should open a form below. It should make a reference to the existing form right? I tried everything but i cant figure it out.

But it opens a new form instead of the form i called "HomeFRM".

How can i open that form?

```
this.Hide();
Form _HomeFRM = new Form();
_HomeFRM.Show();



using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace DELETE
{
public partial class HomeFRM : Form
{
    public HomeFRM()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: You should create an instance of the class derived from the Form class. In your code you have a _variable_ named _HomeFrm but not an instance of whatever class defines your form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that your _HomeFrm form is defined in a file with this content (or like this)

```
namespace MyForms
{
     public class HomeFrm : Form
     {
          public HomeFrm()
          {
               InitializeComponent();
               .....
          }
          .... other methods and event handlers for the HomeFrm class
     }
}
```

Now, if you want to create an instance of this class and show it your code should create the correct class, not the base class

```
// This is required to get access to all classes included
// in the MyForms namespace unless the following code is
// itself inside the same namespace....
using MyForms;   

.....

this.Hide();
HomeFrm myHomeFrm = new HomeFrm();
myHomeFrm.Show();
```

As a side note, I suggest to not start your application with the Login form and the keep it hidden for the lifetime of your application. Insted start with the HomeFrm and inside the constructor start the Login form, save the result of the login in a global variable and in the Form_Load event handler decide if you want to continue or stop the application

Comment: Thanks for Helping!
Yes, my homefrm is defined as a form, so with the content. I tried your code, but it doesn't find a refrence. (screenshot: http://prntscr.com/ci9p8v). Any idea why?

(ps. no need for me to hide the login, since i'ts a personal project which wont be publiced. Thanks anyway!)

Comment: The class HomeFrm (Or whatever you want to call it) should exists in your application. Please add the first lines of the code you have in HomeFrm.cs file (Do not post pictures, instead use the edit link under your question to update )

Comment: Yes, it exists in my application. Code in original post

Comment: The HomeFrm class is inside a namespace called DELETE. To use that class you need to add a _using DELETE;_ in the file where you create the instance of the HomeFrm class (the calling code itself is inside a namespace and the two need to be the same if you want to avoid the using line)

Answer (score 0):

Change to:

```
 this.Hide();
 _HomeFRM newForm = new _HomeFRM();
 newForm.Show();
```

Your custom form is a new Class: "_HomeFRM"

You are creating a new instance of the Form Class (wich is the default empty one) called like your custom one.

Instead, you need to use your form as a Class.